# Making one column merge into another column, and superscript in the merged column (adding pvalue significance in table)

Tags: r, gt

#### Data

```
a <- c("Green", "Red", "Blue", "Orange")
b <- c(100, 408, 39, 102)
c <- c(12000, 3100, 2410, 503)
d <- c("*", "*", "*", "***")
data <- data.frame(a, b, c, d)

data %>% 
  gt()
```

Say I have the above dataframe. Is there a way to make the asterixs in column d, a superscript of column c? So c looks like:
12000^*
3100^* etc?

I am using the `gt` package for tables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to first create an HTML string using e.g. `glue::glue`, then use `gt::fmt_markdown()` to render the text as HTML:

```
library(gt)
library(dplyr)

data |> 
  mutate(c = glue::glue("{c}<sup>{d}</sup>")) |> 
  select(-d) |> 
  gt() |> 
  fmt_markdown(columns = c)
```

[image]